# Bootstrap peer dependency

Tags: vmware-clarity

At the moment you use `bootstrap-4.0.0-alpha.5` as peer dependency.
Any reason why you are still on this version? Which part of bootstrap are you internally using?

Comment: This question appears to be aimed at the maintainers of the package, so it doesn't really belong on SO.

Comment: unfortunately the maintainers of the package say to use SO to submit questions.

Answer (score 0):

If you build a custom theme then you would need to install that version of bootstrap. See https://vmware.github.io/clarity/documentation/v0.11/themes

Comment: thanks for the answer, I was just curious why the version is not the stable one but the alpha

Comment: Simply because we implemented the alpha5 version originally and then Bootstrap had breaking changes that we did not want to pass onto our users. Our long term goal is to remove Bootstrap, but with proper deprecation and migration strategies.